# Handling NULL after if() inside appply

Tags: r, null, apply

I have a situation where `apply` returns a list with many `NULL` entries. The code I use is quite long, so I reproduce the problem with a simple example.

```
# Generate data.
df <- data.frame(a= c(1,2, NA, 6),
                 b= c(1, 7, 3, 7))

# Return only columns that have NAs.
my_list <- apply(df, 2, function(col_i){
  if(any(is.na(col_i))){
    return(col_i)
  }})
```

Running this gives us

```
my_list
$a
[1]  1  2 NA  6

$b
NULL
```

My problem is that I get many `Null` entries so that I can not work with the results. How can I (a) avoid apply to return the `NULL` entries or (b) discard all `NULL` entries in `my_list`?

So the expected output is

```
my_list
$a
[1]  1  2 NA  6
```

Again, the actual code I use is more complex than that. So please do not suggest using something like `df[ , !complete.cases(t(df)), drop= FALSE]` which also returns columns that contain any missings. My question is not about how to get columns with any missings but how to handle `NULL`entries in `apply`. I want to keep the `if` part inside `apply`.

Comment: I would add an `else` branch to the `if`, perhaps returning `NA` or `0`.

Comment: First of all, never run `apply` on a data.frame. Use `laaply` instead. Second of all, just filter your data first and then operate on it, e.g. `df[colSums(is.na(df))]` will return you only the columns you need

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please read the question where I explicitly state that it is not about the `NA` in the columns. The actual situation would make the question unnecessery complicated so I reproduced the problem with a simple example. Also, I see no reason not to use apply. It works with the help of Ronak Shah

Comment: The fact that you don't see it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidArenburg My code runs and answers my research question. I see no reason to change "a running system". Please explain your optinion instead of simply writing "never...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function has to return something so you can't really avoid returning something but you can remove them :

```
Filter(length, apply(df, 2, function(col_i) if(any(is.na(col_i))) return(col_i)))

#$a
#[1]  1  2 NA  6
```